# google python exercises, sample code doesn't run

Tags: python

I'm new to python but not to programming, I'm trying to do the excercises for the google 'class'
http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class

and I'm actually stuck on the first one string1.py, after lots of mussing around with indentation issues I thought I had solved a couple of the problems but i haven't made anything beyond a hello world actually function

but now I'm very confused and frustrated as the supplied answers dont run either, heres the source for the supplied answers i get a syntax error on line 37 this is really frustrating and I dont understand why googles supplied source  for the class wont run :( is this code correct? am i having a compiler problem? what gives? thanks guys!

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

# Google's Python Class
# http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/

# Basic string exercises
# Fill in the code for the functions below. main() is already set up
# to call the functions with a few different inputs,
# printing 'OK' when each function is correct.
# The starter code for each function includes a 'return'
# which is just a placeholder for your code.
# It's ok if you do not complete all the functions, and there
# are some additional functions to try in string2.py.


# A. donuts
# Given an int count of a number of donuts, return a string
# of the form 'Number of donuts: <count>', where <count> is the number
# passed in. However, if the count is 10 or more, then use the word 'many'
# instead of the actual count.
# So donuts(5) returns 'Number of donuts: 5'
# and donuts(23) returns 'Number of donuts: many'
def donuts(count):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  if count < 10:
    return 'Number of donuts: ' + str(count)
  else:
    return 'Number of donuts: many'
  # LAB(replace solution)
  # return
  # LAB(end solution)


# B. both_ends
# Given a string s, return a string made of the first 2
# and the last 2 chars of the original string,
# so 'spring' yields 'spng'. However, if the string length
# is less than 2, return instead the empty string.
def both_ends(s):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  if len(s) < 2:
    return ''
  first2 = s[0:2]
  last2 = s[-2:]
  return first2 + last2
  # LAB(replace solution)
  # return
  # LAB(end solution)


# C. fix_start
# Given a string s, return a string
# where all occurences of its first char have
# been changed to '*', except do not change
# the first char itself.
# e.g. 'babble' yields 'ba**le'
# Assume that the string is length 1 or more.
# Hint: s.replace(stra, strb) returns a version of string s
# where all instances of stra have been replaced by strb.
def fix_start(s):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  front = s[0]
  back = s[1:]
  fixed_back = back.replace(front, '*')
  return front + fixed_back
  # LAB(replace solution)
  # return
  # LAB(end solution)


# D. MixUp
# Given strings a and b, return a single string with a and b separated
# by a space '<a> <b>', except swap the first 2 chars of each string.
# e.g.
#   'mix', pod' -> 'pox mid'
#   'dog', 'dinner' -> 'dig donner'
# Assume a and b are length 2 or more.
def mix_up(a, b):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  a_swapped = b[:2] + a[2:]
  b_swapped = a[:2] + b[2:]
  return a_swapped + ' ' + b_swapped
  # LAB(replace solution)
  # return
  # LAB(end solution)


# Provided simple test() function used in main() to print
# what each function returns vs. what it's supposed to return.
def test(got, expected):
  if got == expected:
    prefix = ' OK '
  else:
    prefix = '  X '
  print '%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected))


# Provided main() calls the above functions with interesting inputs,
# using test() to check if each result is correct or not.
def main():
  print 'donuts'
  # Each line calls donuts, compares its result to the expected for that call.
  test(donuts(4), 'Number of donuts: 4')
  test(donuts(9), 'Number of donuts: 9')
  test(donuts(10), 'Number of donuts: many')
  test(donuts(99), 'Number of donuts: many')

  print
  print 'both_ends'
  test(both_ends('spring'), 'spng')
  test(both_ends('Hello'), 'Helo')
  test(both_ends('a'), '')
  test(both_ends('xyz'), 'xyyz')


  print
  print 'fix_start'
  test(fix_start('babble'), 'ba**le')
  test(fix_start('aardvark'), 'a*rdv*rk')
  test(fix_start('google'), 'goo*le')
  test(fix_start('donut'), 'donut')

  print
  print 'mix_up'
  test(mix_up('mix', 'pod'), 'pox mid')
  test(mix_up('dog', 'dinner'), 'dig donner')
  test(mix_up('gnash', 'sport'), 'spash gnort')
  test(mix_up('pezzy', 'firm'), 'fizzy perm')


# Standard boilerplate to call the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: "i get a syntax error on line 37" What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Code above has `print` statements which work only on Python 2.

Comment: Running fine with python2.7, with python3.5 I get a syntax error in line 102: `print '%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected))
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. By the way line 37 is not even code but a blank line between two comments instead.

Comment: @a_guest That's a Python 2 `print` statement.

Comment: Parentheses are missing on the print statement